# Keeping autolayout after view transform(rotation) and resize(to bounds)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, core-graphics

I have a view with circle subview on one corner of the view.
I defined the circle's position by autolayout.

I need to rotate and resize the base view.

The problem is that if I rotate and then resize the view, position of the circle won't be where I expect it to be.

How do I keep layout in such a situation?

#### No resize or rotaion.

[image]

#### After rotation and resize

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ExampleController: UIViewController {

// UI Appearance

private let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 40
private var themeColor: UIColor = UIColor.magentaColor()



// Resizing and rotating view

let myView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.layer.borderWidth = 1
    v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.magentaColor().CGColor

    v.frame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 225)

    return v
}()

lazy var cornerButton: UIView = {
    let b = UIView()

    b.layer.cornerRadius = self.buttonWidth / 2
    b.layer.borderWidth  = 1
    b.layer.borderColor  = self.themeColor.CGColor

    return b
}()



// Control 

@IBOutlet weak var angleSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var widthSlider: UISlider!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupSubviews()
}


func setupSubviews() {
    view.addSubview(myView)
    view.addSubview(angleSlider)


    // Angle Slider
    angleSlider.minimumValue = 0
    angleSlider.maximumValue = 360
    angleSlider.value        = 0

    // Width Slider
    widthSlider.maximumValue = Float(view!.frame.width)
    widthSlider.value        = Float(myView.frame.width)

    // Corner Button
    myView.addSubview( cornerButton )
    myView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(\(buttonWidth))]", views: cornerButton) // Use extension to set width or height
    myView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(\(buttonWidth))]", views: cornerButton) // Use extension to set width or height
    myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cornerButton, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .Top,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}







// Rotation

@IBAction func angleSliderDidChange(slider: UISlider) {
    print(slider.value)
    setAngle(forMyView: slider.value )
}

func setAngle(forMyView angle: Float) {
    let radian = angle.degreesToRadians
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( radian )
}





// Resize

@IBAction func widthSlider(sender: UISlider) {

    let newWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(sender.value)

    let newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, myView.aspectRatioKeptHeight(forWidth: newWidth))
    myView.bounds.size = newSize

}


}
```

Comment: If you are using AutoLayout, why are you also setting the view frame? Also, the "swift" way of making a CGRect is just that - CGRect instead of CGRectMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.

It was tricky but very simple.

I stated changing bounds when the angle is 0 would not break the layout.
This means I just had to temporary set angle to 0 when I change the bounds.

Complete process is...

1. store current angle
2. set the view's angle to 0
3. set new bounds
4. set the stored angle

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to make the circle a subview of the rectangle that you are applying transforms to and make sure the rectangle view's `clipsToBounds` is set to false. The circle will also have the transforms applied to it, given the information you provide I am not 100% sure this is what you want. If you provide more detail we can refine the answer.

Another way would be to constrain the circle to the top and trailing edge of the rectangle view without making it a subview. You again would have to confirm the given results meet your requirements.

**Problem**: Whatever you do you need to change the `func widthSlider(sender: UISlider)` method as you cannot mix auto layout and use of frames this way. You set a width constraint and height constraint on the rectangle then adjust the constraint's constant. This would require you to store the default dimensions somewhere else.

```
@IBAction func widthSlider(sender: UISlider) {

    let newWidth = CGFloat(sender.value)
    rectangleViewWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth
    let newHeight = myView.aspectRatioKeptHeight(forWidth: newWidth)
    rectangleViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeigh


}
```